# Gulp as file watcher in webstorm

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm working in WebStorm and it asking me if I want to set a file watcher to compile .scss files. So here's my question, is there a way to do it with gulp? If yes, how do I need to code the task?
And btw new with any of compilers, I have never used any .scss compiler, so I would appreciate any help.

Comment: there is glup-sass package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass you can run it inside "terminal" window of webstorm

Comment: I have already installed it, but if you can tell me step by step how to set it as file watcher, I'd be very thankfull.

Comment: Better to have your watch tasks run independently of your IDE, so that it's not tied down to it

Comment: you need to follow instruction - specify where the files are , add configurations to gulpfile.js file etc...

Comment: @DominicTobias So u say setting gulp compiler as file watcher is not optimal option? I wanted to sync it with react (which auto rerender whenever some changes is made in files). If I run independently of IDE, I would need run task everytime to compile .scss. Automatic compiles would be more comfortable for me.

Comment: webstorm docs recommends  to install sass watcher using rubi https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/transpiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html

Comment: Yeah that makes sense (I would use webpack on it's own but should do the same thing). I was confused why webstorm is asking you about that though, as normally those tasks run in a terminal independently of an IDE (I haven't used webstorm before)

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I know, but gulp have image optimilization etc. Not to mention that I was given task to recode php with gulp frontend to react, so I auto started thinking to sync react with gulp.

Comment: why dont you try create- react-app, which have  lot of various tools for react combined and you also can add sass (https://medium.com/@Connorelsea/using-sass-with-create-react-app-7125d6913760)

Comment: @happyZZR1400 I added it, but when I created .scss file, webstorm asked me to set file watcher and set extension program as compiler for .scss files.

Comment: i guess you can ignore webstorm, it tries to help you where you dont need